# How to send email from PHP to Outlook 2010

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a web-based system, and I want to send notification email from the website to system end-users. I did not do that ever in my life so I searched and I did this:

```
<?php

$dbhost="xxx";
$dbuser="xxx";
$con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, "");
if (!$con) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('xxx');

require_once('libs/phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 
$m = new phpMailer;
$m->isSMTP();
$m->SMTPAuth = true;
$m->SMTPDebug = 2;

$m->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
$m->Username = 'xxx';
$m->Password = 'xxx';
$m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$m->Port = 587;
$m->From = 'xxx';
$m->FromName = 'xxx';
$m->addReplyTo('xxx','Reply Address');
$m->addAddress('xxx','xxx');
$m->addCC('xxx','xxx');
$m->addBCC('xxx','xxx');
$m->Subject = 'Subject';
$m->Body = 'This is the body';
$m->AltBody = 'This is the body';
var_dump($m->send());
if ($m->send())
{
    echo "success";
}
else 
{
    echo $m->ErrorInfo;

}

?>
```

I got this error : SMTP connect() failed.

What exactly Host,Username,Password and Port should be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP Server has its settings like host, username,password and port which needs to be set in the above code. The same can be taken from the server administrator.

Alternatively you can use PHP mail() function. Sample Code below:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: test@mailinator.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: test@mailinator.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Host and Port can be obtained from the email provider. The Username and Password are your email and password for example:

For GMAIL : assume I have an email id of **xyz@gmail.com** having password **1709**.

```
$m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$m->Username = 'xyz@gmail.com';
$m->Password = '1709';
$m->Port = 587;
```

You can find settings for any email provider by making a search in your favourite search engine such as "Outlook SMTP Settings" , "Yahoo SMTP Settings" etc.

Comment: Well u can upvote this, so that others can get help from this.

Comment: I did now, nice lesson ^^